# Getx Flutter - Updating item in list is not reactive

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-getx

I am using getx as my statemanagment for my flutter app. But I am having difficulties by updating the values in a list. So I have a usermodel with a parameter of isFollowing. When I click on a button the isFollowing variable shall change and the color should be updated. But it is not happening. I am using Obx as my widget, as I already injected the state at the beginning. It is all working fine with fetching the data and displaying it on the frontend. But when I wanna change the values in my list, it is not updating. My minimal reproducible example

**HomeController**

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var userslist = List<User>().obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchUsers();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchUsers() async {
    var users= await ApiService().getapidata('${usersurl}feed');
    if (users!= null) {
      userslist.value= users;
    }
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
class User {
  User({
    this.id,
    this.user_name,
    this.profile_picture,
    this.isFollowing,
  });

  int id;
  String user_name;
  String profile_picture;
  bool isFollowing;


  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        id: json["id"],
        user_name: json["user_name"],
        profile_picture: json["profile_picture"],
        isFollowing: json["is_following"],
      );
```

**View**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final HomeController homeController = Get.put(HomeController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        child: Obx(
          () => ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: homeController.usersList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return UserWidget(homeController.usersList[index], index);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UserWidget**

```
class UserWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  final int index;
  UserWidget (this.user, this.index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap : ()=> user.isFollowing = true // When I click on this the container it  shall be updated to yellow
        child: Obx( () => Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: user.isFollowing ? Colors.yellow : Colors.black ), // Here is the update I wanna make
      ))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post your getapidata method of APIServices class

Comment: @Coding Hotel, Have you find the solution for this?

Comment: change following statement only `userslist.value= users;`  to `userlist.addAll(users)`

Comment: or else try replacing `userlist.value = users` to `userlist(users)` and pass `ListView.builder` a unique key it worked for me

Answer (score 15):

it worked for me. After making changes to your reactive list, add Example:

```
if (users!= null) {
      userslist.value= users;

      userlist.refresh();
    }
```

Comment: if update any one value of one Item how to update Obx?

Comment: here we update the entire list after updating the item. It will be updated with Obx since the list is already RxList.

Answer (score 6):

In your **fetchUsers** method instead of using

```
userslist.value= users;
```

use

```
userslist.assignAll(users);
```

Comment: thanks.. I was using something like userslist.value.addAll(users) which wasn't working. after changing it to assignAll, the widget re-rendered

Answer (score 4):

Please use the GetBuilder for this.

```
onTap : (){ 
    user.isFollowing = true // When I click on this the container it  shall be updated to yellow
    controller.update()
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. I have a List<String, dynamic> to load a list of checkbox and this wok perfectly.

Comment: or you can use user.refresh(). when model class changed then it need to call refresh for refreshing data

Answer (score 3):

after you assign a new value to the array list. just use the refresh function that is provided by getX then the UI will reload with new data

```
 yourlist.refresh();
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of trying to update an element in the list, create a temporary element update it as you want and swap the list element with it. List elements are the observables not the attributes of these elements.

Comment: You are right, that is what i did for a user map containing friend and friend requests list

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing a property of an item in a list give all items in the list a unique Id. The visual won't update unless you provide it with a unique id.
https://pub.dev/packages/uuid

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

convert your list to a RxList, use the command below to add an element,

```
yourList.insert(elementYouWantToInsertAtTheEnd);
```

use the command below to update the list with a new list,

```
yourList.assignAll(newListYouWantToAssign);
```

This will automatically update the list in GetxController.